# What is this new syntax gql`string`?

Tags: javascript, graphql-js

Consider:

```
const GET_DOGS = gql`
  {
    dogs {
      id
      breed
    }
  }
`;
```

I found this new syntax from [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/queries.html).

What is the explanation for this syntax? Where can I find detail about it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Why does this down voted?  I had the same question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's called a [**tagged template**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates). Template literals (`` `...` ``) can be prefixed with a *function name*. Upon evaluation, this function will be called and the static and dynamic parts of the template literal are passed to the function. Example:

```js
function foo(staticParts, dynamicParts) {
  console.log(staticParts, dynamicParts);
}

foo`this is a ${42} test`
```

Tagged templates can be used to create [domain specific languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language), such as in this example.

There are [many questions around tagged templates](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+tagged+templates) you can learn more from.

Answer (score 2):

It's called a template literal.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Not only does it allow you to do multi-line formatting like your example above, but it also makes it easier to mix expressions in with string content.